# No such module 'AppTrackingTransparency' Error

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to update my Google AdMob account as Apple announced a new transparency framework that requires changes to the iOS apps with the release of iOS 14. I updated my Google AdMob pod to the latest version (7.64.0). But, when I am trying to use the following code in the App Delegate:-

```
import AppTrackingTransparency
import AdSupport
...
func requestIDFA() {
    ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
    // Tracking authorization completed. Start loading ads here.
    // loadAd()
    })
}
```

I get the following error:-

```
No such module 'AppTrackingTransparency'
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: @Tyler I am using Xcode 11

Answer (score 19, accepted):

it's only available starting from Xcode 12, including beta version.

and to use it

```
import AppTrackingTransparency
import AdSupport

if #available(iOS 14, *) {
   ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
  // Load ads here 
   })
} else {
  // Load ads here 
}
```

Exmaple for RewardedVideoAdsManager

```
class RewardedVideoAdsManager: GADRewardedAd {


static let shared = RewardedVideoAdsManager()

var rewardedAd: GADRewardedAd?

func createAndLoadRewardedAd(unitId: String) -> GADRewardedAd? {
    rewardedAd = GADRewardedAd(adUnitID: unitId)
    let myRequest = GADRequest()
    rewardedAd?.load(myRequest) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Loading failed: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Loading Succeeded")
        }
    }
    return rewardedAd
}
```

}

And in my AppDelegate or First main screen

```
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
            RewardedVideoAdsManager.shared.rewardedAd = RewardedVideoAdsManager.shared.createAndLoadRewardedAd(unitId: "ca-app-pub-8175294120313121/4011630802")
        })
    } else {
        RewardedVideoAdsManager.shared.rewardedAd = RewardedVideoAdsManager.shared.createAndLoadRewardedAd(unitId: "ca-app-pub-8175294120313121/4011630802")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but where is the best place to put the code? AppDelegate?

Comment: They said that  it's should be where  you load an ad, but for me, I create ads manager class and since that, I put  it in 1 place

Comment: @AhmedSafadi can you please post a sample of your ad manager and how you add the apptrakingmanager in it. Also xcode 12 is in beta and cannot upload app with beta anymore so have to wait for final release.

Comment: Yes, I'm facing the same issue as @Zaki, even my debug build is failing.

Comment: @Zaki I implement an example so you can know what a manager means, it just prevents form call everywhere.

Comment: i have banner ad for every view controller in viewdidload method where i request and show. now its necessary  to request for every banner in this method ??ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { 
thanks in advance.

Comment: @AqibZareen, will I was asking my self the same, will what I know is that this notification will show once, so unless the user agrees or disagree we don't need to call it since nothing will happen.

Comment: Thanks , i was missing 

#import AppTrackingTransparency

Answer (score 9):

objective-c :

```
#import <AppTrackingTransparency/AppTrackingTransparency.h>
#import <AdSupport/AdSupport.h>

extern "C" void RequestIDFA()
{
    if (@available(iOS 14, *)) {
        [ATTrackingManager requestTrackingAuthorizationWithCompletionHandler:^(ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatus status) {
        }];
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Which framework or pod need to be added?

Answer (score 0):

the first way:
Update your Xcode version to the latest

the second way:
If you don't want to upgrade, you need to download the AppTrackingTransparency.framework file, drag into your project.