# AppTrackingTransparency module not found in Xcode 11.6

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I am trying to compile my Flutter project in Xcode 11.6, however it shows me the error -

```
ld: framework not found AppTrackingTransparency
```

All my code seems to be working fine, however after research I found out that this is something that is required for iOS 14, but if I download Xcode 12 I won't be able to publish my app in release mode as Apple doesn't accept builds from beta versions.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?
I'm having the same error but can't update to Xcode 12 due to other pods errors

Comment: @Enricoza you will have to reduce the version number of your pods that support Xcode 11, thats what worked for me

Comment: Thanks I was just trying that as I asked you and it worked. Just found the pod that was wrongly updated and reduced its version to a Xcode 11 compatible version. Accepted answer was just throwing me off. You should post the comment as an answer for everyone else to see instead of the accepted answer.

Comment: @Enricoza I've changed it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked for me was that I was using a pod that was only supported for Xcode 12 that contained the AppTrackingTransparency framework as it is now a requirement if you are integrating any API that is an ad network, so check if your pods have gotten updated automatically and downgrade it if you want it to work.

Answer (score 3):

You either wait for the Xcode 12 official release or copy the AppTrackingTransparency.framework into the Xcode 11.6's frameworks folder

Comment: It's probably a stupid question - but where can I get this AppTrackingTransparency.framework? Can I download it somewhere? Or install? I'm using Cordova+Xcode and my build is failing with the same error "framework not found AppTrackingTransparency"

Comment: @dop2000 I got it from Xcode 12 at the time. You have to look into the package contents

Answer (score 1):

If you need help implementing the 'AppTrackingTransparency', you can refer to the following question:-

[No such module 'AppTrackingTransparency' Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63516131/13218692)

Hope this solves your problem:)